# Underscore Index in Python

Tags: python, list, function, indexing

Why is the underscore needed when using an index? Here is a bit of code from code academy.

```
animals = ["aardvark", "badger", "duck", "emu", "fennec fox"]
duck_index = animals.index("duck")    # Use index() to find "duck"

animals.insert(duck_index, "cobra")# Your code here!

print animals # Observe what prints after the insert operation
```

It's very confusing to have `duck_index`, then have `animals.index`. It really throws off the whole thing in my mind.

I tried looking on other sites to see if others have brought this up. But I can't find any answers. Makes sense to have this answered and archived in Stack Overflow.

Why use the "`_index`", why not just use the `.index` for everything. Also what is the major difference between the two?

Comment: `duck_index` is the name of a variable defined on your end **BTW**. You can use any other name like `duckIndex`, etc but for accessing the `index` method, you have to use the `.` operator only, there is nothing confusing I guess?

Comment: `duck_index` is the name of a variable. `duck.index` would be trying to access the property `index` of a duck object. instead of `duck_index` you can call it `duckIndex` or `strawberryCheesecacke` if you want :)

Comment: What would `duck` be that `duck_index` meant the same as `animals.index()`?

Comment: It *is* true that the code fragment in question is somewhat confusing, especially if you are brand new to the language (or even programming). It isn't exactly obvious to someone starting out that the dot on one side of the equals sign is essential but the underscore on the other side of the equation is just stylistic.

Answer (score 2):

An underscore is just another valid character in a variable name, just like the characters `A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`. You use it when you want to separate two words in a single name. It's the recommended practice in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The underscore takes on special meaning when used at the beginning of the name, but I won't get into that here.

The `.` on the other hand is used to access a member of a variable. In this case you're calling the `index` method on the `animals` variable. `animals` and `index` are two different names.

Answer (score 1):

Animal.index ("duck") is looking for index position of "duck" in animal.

While duck _ index  is an indetifier variable that will hold index of duck. The naming makes sense